# How to serve zip file with next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to serve a zip file I created with archiver library on my next js project. Eventhough the file I created is healthy, I can't open the file I downloaded because it is corrupted.

this is how I created my zip file

```
function zipDirectory(sourceDir, outPath) {
    const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outPath);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        archive
            .directory(sourceDir, false)
            .on('error', (err) => reject(err))
            .pipe(stream);

        stream.on('close', () => resolve());
        archive.finalize();
    });
}
```

this is how I serve the file

```
import fs from 'fs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { filePath, fileName } = req.body;
    const fullPath = `${filePath}/${fileName}`;

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);

    let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fullPath);
    fileStream.pipe(res);
}
```

Note : when I check the file size in handler function, it gives different results each time even though the file is same.

Comment: What is in the corrupt archive?  Did you try opening it in a hex editor to see what its contents actually are?  Does it look vaguely zip-like or is it obviously some other content (like an error message that just got saved as .zip by the browser because it got marked application/zip or something?

Comment: It looks like a zip file, I can see some of the file names I put into it. I see that many people have encountered the same problem but I couldn't find proper solution. It seems I have to make some additional configurations for zip files. I can download txt or docx files with this method.